How to (coarsely) estimate turbulent kinetic energy (TKE) dissipation in a large tank?
I'm wondering if it is possible to say something semi-quantitative (approximate order of magnitude) about turbulent kinetic energy (TKE) dissipation in a large tank of water (6 m tall, 3 m wide). The water has been stirred very locally for a few minutes by something basically like a large immersion blender, and then left untouched for several days. There is some possibility of convection due to a slight (1-2 degrees C) temperature difference between the tank and the surrounding air.
My thinking goes along two lines:

If I know the power of the immersion blender, and how long it ran, I know the energy input. Probably some fraction of that went almost directly to heat in the immediate vicinity of the blender, but let's say I can guess at that fraction. Is it then possible to say something about the rate at which the remaining kinetic energy would decay, thus giving me an estimate of TKE dissipation over time?

If I guess at a temperature difference between the tank and the surroundings, I can estimate how much energy in the form of heat goes into (or out of) the tank. Is it then possible to say something about the fraction of that energy that goes to kinetic energy due to buoyancy production?


The reason I ask is that I am trying to make sense of some experiments that were done years ago, in a tank that no longer exists, so I can't do any more measurements. I'm trying to estimate the rate of collision of some particles in the tank, and the expression for collision rate due to turbulence contains the TKE dissipation, $\varepsilon$ (see for example Eq. (7) in Jokulsdottir & Archer (2016)). The two other effects that drive particle collision are Brownian motion (which I can ignore here due to particle size) and differential rise/settling velocities, which I can say something about, as I know the sizes of the particles.
So the bottom line is: If I can say that TKE dissipation is very, very small, say $10^{-10}$ W/kg, then I can definitely ignore collisions due to turbulence relative to differential settling, whereas if it is for example $10^{-5}$ W/kg, then I can't.
I understand that any estimate must be extremely crude, and could be several orders of magnitude off, but any ideas on how to reason around this would be helpful. Even to get the "order of magnitude of the order of magnitude", so to speak, would be useful.
